# Babylon.js - How to get a matte surface

Tags: babylonjs

I am trying to make a surface matte, without success. The StandardMaterial applied to it has only a diffuseColor. I tried playing with "roughness" (between 0 and 7) but the surface is always glossy.

How can get a matte surface?

Comment: Looking through the [docs](http://doc.babylonjs.com/classes/2.2/StandardMaterial)... `useSpecularOverAlpha` or `useGlossinessFromSpecularMapAlpha` might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how to reduce the shininess of a StandardMaterial by setting a darker specularColor: http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#K0ND3#0

Edit: As suggested by Pang here the code for setting a darker specular color to a material:

```
mesh.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial('mat', scene);
mesh.material.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I should remember that a StandardMaterial has a specularColor by default. Setting it to black (0, 0, 0) makes the surface matte.

Comment: @Pang I edited the answer to include the code needed for changing the specular color. I didn't include it first since "setting a darker specularColor" was the answer to the question. The question was not "how do I set a darker specular color". Anyways, I understand that it's better with the code in the answer so I edited it. I don't think the down vote or to recommend deletion was necessary, though, since the answer was there.

Comment: One upvote from myside, I was looking for this from days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do it: if I set the "normal" vector (nx, ny, nz) in the plane of the surface instead of normal to it, then the surface becomes perfectly matte.

That solution looks like a hack. There must be a better way to achieve the same result.